# IONIC white screen problem with splash screen hangs on first time load (iOS - ionic3)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Okay, I know that there are many similar problems out there, but I am facing a little different one.

Actually, when I build my Ionic3 app for iOS using Xcode10, it builds perfectly but when the app launches the first time, it shows the splash screen for a long time and then the white screen stays for infinite time, but if I minimize the app and open again, I see that everything is loaded well and app is working fine(I am facing this both on iOS simulator and on device).

This is happening every time I start the app after closing its task. But after closing it(not to clear its task) and opening it again, it works fine and the white screen goes away.
Though there is no good white screen related solution out there and I tried almost everything but the problem is still there. Please help me.

PS: The same app works perfectly in Android in both debug and production builds(on simulator as well as on device).

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "newApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/fcm": "^4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/google-analytics": "^4.13.0",
    "@ionic-native/push": "4.0.1",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.12.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.91",
    "cordova-android": "^7.1.3",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.9",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": "^1.8.6",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "datepicker-ionic2": "^2.6.2",
    "highcharts": "^4.2.6",
    "ion2-calendar": "^2.2.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.6.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionic-select-searchable": "^2.8.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "rxjs": "5.4.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "2.1.4",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-google-analytics": {
        "GMS_VERSION": "11.0.1"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android",
      "ios"
    ]
  }
}
```

My `config.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="newApp" version="24.6.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>New App</name>
    <description>An Inventory App</description>
    <author email="prashantjain.pro@gmail.com" href="">Prashant Jain</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://ionic.local/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*://*vimeo.com" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
    <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
    <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
    <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />

    <preference name="AutohideSplashScreen" value="false" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <icon density="ldpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="mdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="hdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
        <splash density="land-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="land-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-ldpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-mdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-hdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
        <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
        <icon height="57" src="resources/ios/icon/icon.png" width="57" />
        <icon height="114" src="resources/ios/icon/icon@2x.png" width="114" />
        <icon height="40" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40.png" width="40" />
        <icon height="80" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@2x.png" width="80" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-40@3x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="50" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50.png" width="50" />
        <icon height="100" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-50@2x.png" width="100" />
        <icon height="60" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60.png" width="60" />
        <icon height="120" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" />
        <icon height="180" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" />
        <icon height="72" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72.png" width="72" />
        <icon height="144" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" />
        <icon height="76" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76.png" width="76" />
        <icon height="152" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" />
        <icon height="167" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" />
        <icon height="29" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small.png" width="29" />
        <icon height="58" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" />
        <icon height="87" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-small@3x.png" width="87" />
        <splash height="1136" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="1334" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-667h.png" width="750" />
        <splash height="2208" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-736h.png" width="1242" />
        <splash height="1242" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" />
        <splash height="1536" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape@~ipadpro.png" width="2732" />
        <splash height="768" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" />
        <splash height="2048" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait@~ipadpro.png" width="2048" />
        <splash height="1024" src="resources/ios/splash/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" />
        <splash height="960" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" />
        <splash height="480" src="resources/ios/splash/Default~iphone.png" width="320" />
        <splash height="2732" src="resources/ios/splash/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" width="2732" />
        <icon height="1024" src="resources/ios/icon/icon-1024.png" width="1024" />
    </platform>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.0.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="^2.2.2" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-app-version" spec="^0.1.9" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-google-analytics" spec="^1.8.6">
        <variable name="GMS_VERSION" value="11.0.1" />
    </plugin>
    <engine name="android" spec="^7.1.3" />
    <engine name="ios" spec="4.5.5" />
</widget>
```

Comment: Well, it is possible that your app might take a lot of time to load, so if that is going on, make sure you are showing the splash screen for the whole time till your app loads and then hiding it in the `app.component.ts` when the `platform.ready()` is called.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I figured out the exact problem. It was due to the plugins addition and removal while changing the iOS platform versions. Due to which `device doesn't get ready before loading plugins`.

To solve this, make sure you have added the latest iOS platform. Then start removing plugins one-by-one which are in the `plugins folder`.
To remove a plugin, write:
`ionic cordova plugin rm <plugin-name>`

If its `npm` module is there, then uninstall it as well:
`npm uninstall --save <plugin-name>`

Make sure you remove every plugin this way. Then, refresh your project or clean the project with:
`npm run clean`

Then, start adding the plugins again. Use:
`ionic cordova plugin add <plugin-name>`

`npm install --save <plugin-name>`

After this, just build the project again using:
`ionic cordova build android --prod`

And everything will work fine. :)

PS: If any problem comes up while building like, `version 4 present, expected 3`, then this means, your project is made for `ionic3`, so, in this case, you might have to change the `@ionic-native/core` and `rxjs` version, and then have to change the `version from 4 to 3 in every metadata file in node_modules/@ionic-native`.

Hope, this will solve your problem :)